# validating my app im receiving the message "No identities are available for signing"

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.3, validating

I archived my app and then put it through validation. a window came up titled "Choose an application record and an Identity to sign with" and then a yellow triangle and the message "No identities are available for signing" was displayed and options for Downloading  Identities and Import Developer Profile.
  I  chose Download Identities and received the message after it logged into my IOS Dev Center account  "An administrator must request identities before they can be Downloaded".
[codesigning error warnig http://imageshack.us/a/img824/4080/validate2.gif](http://imageshack.us/a/img824/4080/validate2.gif)
I then chose the "Import Developer Profile" and it and was also unsuccessful.

I checked the code signing and got noticed the error warning no profiles currently match and that and that the application identifier com.jarrahbridges...... profile doesnt match application identifier com.jarrahBridges........

In organiser my provisioning profiles state they are Valid Profiles all my certificates in my key chain (numbering 6) are all valid.

Any direction on this would be most appreciated

Comment: I resolved the problem I modified the distribution provisioning profile in the IOS Dev Centre and then deleted the  provisioning profile that was the problem in the organisers > Provisioning Profiles and the refreshed using the refresh button in the bottom right hand corner of window and every thing corrected it self.

Comment: But it still didnt past validation, it gave me the message that "Icon specified in the info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper"

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem and the problem was my Distribution Certificate was created it on another Mac. Here are more details:

http://spacetech.dk/ios-development-error-no-identities-are-available-for-signing.html

Answer (score 2):

1. Create AppStore provision profile at the Developer Portal, then update xCode profiles (xCode -> Preferences... -> Accounts).
2. Create an achieve and press "Validate"
3. You now are able to validate the archive agains you Distribution Certificate and AppStore Provision profile

Don't know is it a bug or feature, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try following these instructions. Basically there are multiple places where you have to tell Xcode what your bundle identifier is and what the provisioning profile is. I can't believe this stuff is totally overlooked in the iOS Developer Distribution Guide by Apple.

http://anthonytietjen.blogspot.com/2012/08/overcoming-trouble-validating-your.html

Also, go into Build Settings for your project and go to Code Signing. Make sure the Code Signing Identities are all set to the iDevice Distribution App ID you created in iTunes Connect as well as the Provisioning Profile set to the Provisioning Profile you painstakingly created in the iOS Development Center as well (that Ad Hoc provisioning profile file you created and downloaded into Xcode.)
Apple was great at walking you through creating the Distribution Certificate and Ad Hoc Provisioning Profile, but when it comes down to getting things bundled up in Xcode, they left a lot out.

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH1-SW1

I would say that if you still can't get it working with an Ad Hoc provisioning profile, try generating an App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile within the "Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles" portion of the Development center , import it into Xcode (by refreshing the provisioning profile list under Xcode->preferences->accounts->details->refresh button) and go through the validation process of your archive again. I'm not sure if it's because Xcode can't validate an Archive with an Ad Hoc profile or what, but it seems to pick up the Distribution Provisioning Profile just fine and allows you to validate.  Don't worry, even if you don't validate the archive with the Ad Hoc provisioning profile, you can still create the .ipa for your archive by hitting the Distribute button in Organizer->Archives and choosing the Ad Hoc profile so that you can beta test it.